# Executing script out of wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the plugin "wp-video-lightbox" for wordpress that creates little floating boxes for my videos.

I'd like to use variables like `http://www.example.com/?video3` to offer shortcuts like youtube does so I've tried to find a way to execute the script on page load (depending on the variable).

That's the function from the script:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Class: prettyPhoto
        Use: Lightbox clone for jQuery
        Author: Stephane Caron (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com)
        Version: 3.1.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

(function($) {
        $.prettyPhoto = {version: '3.1.5'};

        $.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {

...

            $.prettyPhoto.initialize = function() {

                    settings = pp_settings;

                    if(settings.theme == 'pp_default') settings.horizontal_padding = 16;

                    // Find out if the picture is part of a set
                    theRel = $(this).attr(settings.hook);
                    galleryRegExp = /\[(?:.*)\]/;
                    isSet = (galleryRegExp.exec(theRel)) ? true : false;

                     // Put the SRCs, TITLEs, ALTs into an array.
                    pp_images = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return $(n).attr('href'); }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('href'));
                    pp_titles = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).find('img').attr('alt')) ? $(n).find('img').attr('alt') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
                    pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).attr('rev')) ? $(n).attr('rev') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('rev'));

                    if(pp_images.length > settings.overlay_gallery_max) settings.overlay_gallery = false;

                    set_position = jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('href'), pp_images); // Define where in the array the clicked item is positionned
                    rel_index = (isSet) ? set_position : $("a["+settings.hook+"^='"+theRel+"']").index($(this));

                    _build_overlay(this); // Build the overlay {this} being the caller

                    if(settings.allow_resize)
                            $(window).bind('scroll.prettyphoto',function(){ _center_overlay(); });


                    $.prettyPhoto.open();

                    return false;
            }

...

};
```

})(jQuery);

When I use `<body onload="jQuery.prettyPhoto.initialize">` it seems like the function is returned as string(?). I've tried 
`eval(jQuery.prettyPhoto.initialize)`and 
`F=new Function(jQuery.prettyPhoto.initialize);return(F());` without suceeding.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: do you need to include '()' ? as in: <body onload="jQuery.prettyPhoto.initialize()">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your function is never being invoked.  Try including '()' as such:

```
<body onload="jQuery.prettyPhoto.initialize()">
```

Comment: ... how simple. I will code a workaround for "return false;" and it should work. Thank you